# JPA inferred query with one argument to search using OR operator

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My idea exactly is that I have a Class of Students with fields Parent mother and Parent father. I get an id and want to find all students(that are children) of this parent. And want to use inferred query. Only thing is I don't find anything on the internet that suggests using one argument to search in two fields' results. This is what I currently have:

```
List<Class> classes = repository.findAllByStudentsMotherIdOrStudentsFatherId(parentId);
```

Trying to do it only returns me this:

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List io.soft.ejournal.repository.ClassRepository.findAllByStudentsMotherIdOrStudentsFatherId(java.lang.Long)! Method public abstract java.util.List io.soft.ejournal.repository.ClassRepository.findAllByStudentsMotherIdOrStudentsFatherId(java.lang.Long) expects at least 2 arguments but only found 1. This leaves an operator of type SIMPLE_PROPERTY for property students.father.id unbound.
```

So aparently using `or` requires having two arguments? Is there a way to use this sort of querying?

Comment: You to pass two arguments to validate. Check this [Derived Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries)

Answer (score 0):

When using [Derived Queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries), you need to supply the number of arguments that match on what the method name requires. So answering your question, **Yes** it requires having two arguments.

For your second question, you can try and use [QueryDsl](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-querydsl) to create predicates for your query.